# Union Typing in Z3

Tags: z3

Suppose I have the following type system:

```
Type :=
    A ; type of A
    B ; type of B
    C ; type of C
    Int ; type of int
    Real ; type of real
v := 
    abc ; value of abc
    real ; value of real
    int ; value of int
t :=
    v ; values can be mapped to terms
    <abc_0, abc_1,... abc_n> = break abc' into int ; this will break abc' into real parts (think of this as a generic partitioning or division operation.
    abc = op abc' for int ;
    + ; math plus operator, assume this "works" for types A|B|C, and works as expected for Int|Real
```

Suppose that the body of `op` and `break` is as such:

```
; op return type could, maximally, be the union of x, y, z, or minimally be the union types of x, y or x, z
op(x, y): ; recall, x:{A|B|C} and y:{A|B|C}
    A z;
    while([some condition]):
        if ([another condition]):
            x += y
        else:
            x += z
    return x

break(x, y):
     ; For simplicity, this can just return an array of y-size, whose type is that of x
     ; in implementation this is much more complicated than this, but for simplicity this suffices to articulate the concept.
     return array[y];
```

Now I'm given this program, with dynamic typing:

```
a = ... ; this is of {A|B|C}
x = 5 ; typeof Int

b = op a for x
c = break b into x
```

I need to prove the satisfiability of this program, using Z3.

I'm really not sure how to represent this program in z3.  The union typing, I think can be handled by the custom datatypes below.  But I am unclear how to handle loops/conditionals.  Just as in sentential logic, do they translate to `forall` or `there exists at least one` quantifiers?

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Type A B C)))

(define-sort Set (T) (Array T Type))

(declare-fun break_func (Type Real) (Set Type))
; not sure if this is correct or not...
(declare-fun op_func (Type Real) (Set Type))

(declare-const a Type)
(declare-const x Int)

; not quite sure what to put my for asserts....
; should I assert that the size of the break_func matches the input?  If so, how
; I don't understand how to type check the output for op_func

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

My main questions, aside from "is this correct" is that:

1. The Z3 implementation of this isn't a full representation of the program, but I don't understand what asserts I should be using for my Z3 implementation for this use-case
2. I don't understand how to account for union typing in Z3?

Comment: It is hard to figure out exactly what you are asking, unfortunately. I'd recommend taking a look at prior work in this area first. See this paper for starters, for example: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/icfp09i-bierman.pdf

Comment: What is your goal here? Are you trying to use Z3 to prove that a particular program is type correct?

Comment: Sorry, yes, my goal is to use z3 to prove that a program is type correct.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify that you are trying to prove a program type correct? Please include the exact program you want to prove type correct and a description of the type system you want to work in.

Comment: Your edits have made the question much more clear, thanks. I'm still confused about your type system, though. Suppose `a : A` and `b : B`, what is the type of `a + b`? What are the return types of `op` and `break`?

Comment: @JamesWilcox, The type of  `a + b` would be `{A|B}`.  Or, the union type `A|B`.  The return type of `op` is going to be is going to be a value/term `abc`.  So a value of `abc : {A|B|C}`, or a union of whatever the inputs are.  And the output for `break` is going to be a set of `n-values` whose length is `n` (the input into the function).  So if you ran `break(abc, 5)` the return would be a set of 5 elements where each element is `abc`.

Comment: Also note, that I changed the comment for op/break to reflect what I said, with a bit more clarity.  I added the details regarding the typing output.  Such that: op's return type will maximally be the `union(x, y, z)` or minimally be the `union(x, y)` or `union(x, z)`.  And the typing output of break is that of the input `x`.